# Plotting mean of medians on image coordinates

Tags: matlab, plot, mean

Due to my limited knowledge in Matlab i am struggling to plot mean of medians on the image coordinates. I have a gray scale image in Matlab. I want to plot its mean of the medians of its columns on that image so that it divides the image into two parts horizontally. I have obtained mean by using Matlab's 'Mean' command. But i am struggling to get image coordinates where i can plot the mean of medians.

After slight modification in Marcin's code i was able to get this output which shows median of columns of a grayscale image.

The modified code is,

```
load clown 

M = median(X, 1);
figure();
imshow(uint8(X)); one=zeros(1,numel(M));
hold on;

for columnIdx = 1:numel(M)
    medianValue = M(columnIdx);

    % find locations of gray-scale lavel values equal to the median        
    idx = find(X(:, columnIdx) == medianValue);
    selectone=floor(length(idx)/2); % selecting the middle value 

    % create a vector containing median values for each column    
    if (isempty(idx) == 1); 
        one(1,columnIdx)=svone; 
    else
        one(1,columnIdx)=idx(selectone); 
    end   

    % in case when median value doesn't matches columns values use the
    % previous column median value
    svone=one(1,columnIdx);    
end
plot(1:numel(M), one, '-g');
```

The output is,

[image: Medians of columns of gray scale image]

I want to plot the mean of the medians of the columns so that it should divide the image horizontally in two parts. Can anyone help me in this or give an idea about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if i understand you correctly, you want to plot another line in that figure over the same xrange as the green line, just with a constant y-value. That constant value shall be the mean of the y-values of the green line, this can be done with `line` or `plot` where we just need to define start and ending point:

```
plot([1, numel(M)], [mean(one), mean(one)], 'r-')
```

Comment: yes thats working good. can i plot the median in the same way? or should i have to go through column by column in for loop?